# CustomCell with Swift and separate Class with Prototype cells

Tags: uitableview, swift

All,

I have a sample project, which is a tableview with a prototype cells. 
I am trying to create a customCell , and I have created a class and I have linked the class to the prototype cell.

Here is my code :

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var SampleTextLabel: UILabel!

}
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var items: [String] = ["I", "Hate", "Swift"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as CustomCell


    //cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

No matter what I do , I cannot get to cell.sampleTextLabel, I have added the as CustomCell on the end of the dequeue line. Anyone got any ideas why I cannot see the label ?

All the best,

Comment: Did you specify the base class for your cell prototype? Are you sure your cell prototype has (a) added a new label to the cell; and (b) the outlet from this label has been hooked up to the custom class label outlet?

Comment: Also, have you set up the constraints for the label? Check the frame for the label. You can run app, hit pause button, and at `(lldb)` prompt, enter `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`. That will show you the frames for all of your views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
var cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCell
cell.SampleTextLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
return cell
```

Comment: @Rob - Ahh, you're right, missed that in the op.  You still need to call `forIndexPath:` in the dequeue though correct?

Comment: The `forIndexPath` is preferred and should be used, but not technically necessary.